# Google API Key for Local Testing

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-translate

Is there any way to get a Google API key for local testing purposes? I intend to use some of the Google APIs mainly for educational purposes (i.e For learning about it..) and I need to generate an API key without supplying a web site URL..Thanks in advance..

P.S: If it helps I'm trying to learn about Google Translate API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can supply a local host name (e.g. `localhost` or `testserver`) when generating the API key.

Answer (score 0):

Q) Is there any way to get a Google API key for local testing purposes?
Ans:- There seems no way to have google maps API key free without credit card.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32769060)